# How can i detect USB is inserted or not for linux in C

Tags: c, linux, usb

I am new in C programming 
Here i want to detect USB is inserted or not in Linux 
I want to detect this things on my embedded linux device. which have customized linux.
So i want to detect the block of USB where i have to mount this block. like `sda,sdb or sdc`.
I want to o this thing in C programming for linux.

Here i have path for usb devices `/sys/bus/usb/devices`
i can see usb information is available is here `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-x`
so i want to fetch the address of block where this usb is inserted like `sda,sdb or sdc`.
So now after fetching this address name i have to mount usb on particular path.

so can anybody please suggest me how can i detect usb is inserted or not if inserted than how can i know address of this

Comment: Does your embedded device run hal or UDisks?

Comment: i cant get you. what u mean? may be Udisks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084740/udev-run-program-on-usb-flash-drive-insert . You can create your code in C/C++ to be executed upon usb insertion (instead of monitoring the usb from your code).

Comment: https://github.com/Jinjinov/Usb.Events/blob/master/Usb.Events/UsbEventWatcher.Linux.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up a hotplug event handler: You will get a hotplug block event when a block device appears or goes away, which you can use to mount/umount and run your handler scripts and apps.

Comment: For that first i need to parse some path and need to know about my address than i will mount.

Answer (score 3):

Udisk can meet your needs, but You should have some understanding of the D-Bus.
And the d-bus daemon should run in you embedded linux first.

the follows I write is to detect udisk program before I known D-Bus. It's very bad, But may be give your prompt.
key path: "/dev/disk/by-uuid"
key file: "/etc/mtab"
This show how to mount the udisk by comparing them.

```
/*
 * This program demonstrates method
 * detect U disk and mount it
 * if main exit umount it
 *
 * note: run as root
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *dirpath;
    char *filename;

    dirpath = "/dev/disk/by-uuid";
    filename = "/etc/mtab";

    //step 1. open dir and file
    DIR *dirp;
    FILE *mtab;

    //FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);
    if((mtab = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "open %s failed\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }


    //DIR *opendir(const char *name);
    if((dirp = opendir(dirpath)) == NULL){
        fprintf(stdout, "opendir %s failed\n", dirpath);
        exit(1);
    }else{
        fprintf(stdout, "opendir %s successfully\n", dirpath);
    }

    //step 1.5 show content of dirpath
#if 0
    struct dirent {
        ino_t          d_ino;       /* inode number */
        off_t          d_off;       /* offset to the next dirent */
        unsigned short d_reclen;    /* length of this record */
        unsigned char  d_type;      /* type of file; not supported
                           by all file system types */
        char           d_name[256]; /* filename */
    };
#endif

    struct dirent *direntp;

    errno = 0;
    //struct dirent *readdir(DIR *dirp);
    while((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL){
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", direntp->d_name);

    }
    if(errno != 0){
        perror("readdir failed");
        exit(1);
    }


    //void rewinddir(DIR *dirp);
    rewinddir(dirp);

    //step 1.6 get mounted device name
    char mdev[64][255];
    int i;
    int devnum;

    i = 0;
    //int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
    while(fscanf(mtab, "%s", mdev[i]) != EOF){
        //int getc(FILE *stream);
        while(getc(mtab) != '\n')
            ;

        //int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);
        if(strncmp(mdev[i], "/dev/sd", 7) == 0 &&
           strncmp(mdev[i], "/dev/sda", 8) != 0){
            fprintf(stdout, "mdev: %s\n", mdev[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }

    strncpy(mdev[i], "", 1);

    //step 2. check content
    char buf[255];
    char path[255];
    char cmd[255];
    char *p;
    int flag;       /* if 0 not mount, if 1 mount */

    devnum = i;

    errno = 0; 
    //struct dirent *readdir(DIR *dirp);
    while((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL){
        flag = 1;

        if(direntp->d_name[0] == '.'){ /* remove . and .. */
            continue;
        }
        //int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);
        snprintf(path, sizeof(path) - 1, "%s/%s",dirpath, direntp->d_name);

        //ssize_t readlink(const char *path, char *buf, size_t bufsiz);
        if(readlink(path, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1) < 0){
            perror("readlink failed");
            exit(1);
        }

        p = strrchr(buf, '/');
        if(p != NULL && strncmp(p, "/sda", 4) != 0){ /* remove sda* */
            //char *strchr(const char *s, int c);
            snprintf(path, sizeof(path) - 1, "/dev%s", p);

            fprintf(stdout, "step 2. %s, devnum = %d\n", path, devnum);

            for(i = 0; i < devnum; i++){ /* check mount */
                if(strcmp(mdev[i], path) == 0){
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //step 3. mount umounted usb
            if(flag == 1){
                fprintf(stdout, "need mount %s\n", path);

                //int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);
                snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd) - 1, "sudo mount %s /mnt", path);
                if(system(cmd) < 0){
                    fprintf(stderr, "system() %s failed: %s\n", 
                        path, strerror(errno));
                }
            }
        }

    }
    if(errno != 0){
        perror("readdir failed");
        exit(1);
    }


    sleep(10);

    //step 4. umount usb
    //int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);
    snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd) - 1, "sudo umount /mnt");
    if(system(cmd) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "system() %s failed: %s\n", 
            path, strerror(errno));
    }

    //step 5. close dir
    //int closedir(DIR *dirp);
    closedir(dirp);
    fclose(mtab);

    return 0;

}
```