# How to prperly launch mjpg_streamer when a webcam is pluged in?

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to launch mjpg streamer when a webcam is plugged in.
So far I've been able to detect when the webcam is pluged and I've been able to launch it.

But two issues appear:

- first the port doesn't appear to be open
- second the process is killed after about 3 minutes

  Im running on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

here is what I assume is the culprit file

**/etc/udev/rules.d/10-usbmount.rules**

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084740/udev-run-program-on-usb-flash-drive-insert
KERNEL=="video[0-9]*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/usr/bin/usbdevinserted"
```

**/usr/bin/usbdevinserted**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $DEVNAME 2>&1 > /tmp/usbdevinfo
#set 2>&1 >> /tmp/usbdevinfo
if [[ $(pgrep mjpg_streamer) ]];
then
    echo "Stoping Mjpg_Streamer" 2>&1 >> /tmp/usbdevinfo;
    pkill mjpg_streamer;
    echo "mjpg_Streamer stoped" 2>&1 >> /tmp/usbdevinfo;
fi
if [[ $(v4l2-ctl --device=$DEVNAME --all | grep "Video input") ]];
then
    echo "launching mjpg_streamer on $DEVNAME" 2>&1 >> /tmp/usbdevinfo;
    (mjpg_streamer -i "input_uvc.so -f 15 -r 1080x720 -d $DEVNAME" -o "output_http.so -w /pathToHome/mjpg-streamer/www -p 8080" 2>&1 >> /tmp/usbdevinfo) | at now
fi
```